# Select statement returns the wrong match (ignores special characters)

Tags: sql-server-2014

I have the table `Exceptions` where a row with column named `[Value]` equals the string `Ceakcacohkka`. When running the query:

```
SELECT * FROM Exceptions WHERE Value='Čeakčačohkka'
```

The above mentioned row is returned. `SQL Server` somehow ignores the special chars and matches this `[Value]` to the string provided.

If I change the string to `Čeakčačohkka` the same select statement returns no rows!

How is this possible? Something with international settings?

Comment: Tty with Value=N'Čeakčačohkka'. Then try with Collate.

Comment: it would be usefull to know which datatype [Value] has and which Collation you are using in this database...

Comment: Thanks Giorgi, adding N before did the job!